# [Android][Espresso] AppNotIdle Exception: how to find running UI/Main thread?

Tags: android, android-espresso

When I am running Espresso in android,it has an error:

```
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3762 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
```

After I google it, I found the reason because the main/ui thread is not idle. So I use the below code to print all of the running thread.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 TimerTask delayedThreadStartTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //captureCDRProcess();
                //moved to TimerTask
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        dumpThreads();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(delayedThreadStartTask, 15 * 1000); //1 minute


      static  void dumpThreads() {
        int activeCount = Thread.activeCount();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[activeCount];
        LogHelper.i("*****************************************************");
        Thread.enumerate(threads);
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            LogHelper.e(thread.getName() +": Id "+thread.getId() +": " + thread.getState());
            for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : thread.getStackTrace()) {
                LogHelper.e("\t" + stackTraceElement);
            }
        }
    }
```

These are the thread information from [log](https://github.com/fhlkm/Espresso/wiki/Log):

However, I didn't find UI/main thread inside. Anyone know why?